# Quadratic Diophantine equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratics, diophantine-equations

how one can approach solving diophantine equation $a^{2}$+ $b^{2}$ - $1$ = $n {\cdot}a{\cdot}b$ in positive integers $a$, $b$, $n$ ( where also $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime)? I have tried so far only to treat it as quadratic one, and solve for discriminant, but am unable to get decent result. Also, i got $a{\cdot}b$|($a-b-1){\cdot}(a-b+1)$, and am not sure where to move from that result. Thanks in each case, any help or resource for solving these is appreciated.

Comment: probably vieta jumping, but you have slightly different from the original problems. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping

Comment: Note that $a=1,\ b=k,\ n=k$ give a (perhaps trivial) family of solutions.

Comment: Your result of $a{\cdot}b$|($a-b-1){\cdot}(a-b+1)$ appears to indicate you already know this but, just in case you don't (as well as for anybody else who's interested), one fairly basic family of solutions is that, with $n=2$, we get $a^2-2ab+b^2=1 \; \to \; (a-b)^2 = 1$. Thus, $a-b=1 \; \to \; a = b + 1$, or $a-b=-1 \; \to \; a = b - 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We demand $n \geq 3.$

as you have $x^2 - nxy+y^2 = 1,$    all   solutions come from   applying the mapping
$$  (x,y)  \mapsto (nx-y , x )   $$  beginning with the pair $(1,0).$

Along with those,  one may switch  $(x,y) $  to $(y,x).$   Also negate  both $(-x,-y)$

$$  (1,0); \; (n,1);  \;   (n^2-1,n);  \; (n^2-1,n);  \; (n^3 - 2n, n^2 - 1 ); ........ 
             $$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).